# I need to allow one account per IP address?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am using the following to grab the users IP address:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Then I follow it by adding this to the database upon registration:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO members (FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Address,City,State,Zip,Pin,IP_Address) VALUES ('$_POST[FirstName]','$_POST[LastName]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Phone]','$_POST[Address]','$_POST[City]','$_POST[State]','$_POST[Zip]','$_POST[pin]','" . $ip . "')";
```

It inserts the IP address in the proper field and it grabs the right one, but I want to be able to have it error if the IP address exists.

Allowing only one account per IP address so people don't spam the account creation form.

So clearly by the comments restricting users by the IP address wouldn't be the best way of doing this since it would block off networks from using the services like a school/library.

What is the best way to limit users to 1 account without using email address since they could just have a catchall address and setup 1@domain.com - 2@domain.com - 3@domain.com ... etc.

Comment: Bad database design, meet `NAT`. `NAT`, meet bad database design.

Comment: So, 2 people won't be able to create an account from the same shared internet connection?

Comment: Entire schools or workplaces would be stymied by this, wherein every user appears to the broad Internet as originating from the same NAT address.

Comment: Most ISPs use dynamic IP addresses. This will never work they way you want it to.

Comment: 1 ip can be many people, many ip's can be one person

Comment: Ah I see your point. Is there a better way I can could limit 1 account per person other than by email address. Because they could just setup false email addresses with catchall on and create infinite accounts.

Comment: validate the emailIds using regular expression, and make login and email unique.

Answer (score 1):

create a unique index on the IP_Address column:

SQL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX one_user_per_ip ON members (IP_Address);
```

As others have said, this sort of constraint may prove less useful than you think.
and it will pretty-much stop woriking entirely once IPV6 comes online and everyone gets a bucketload of addresses each.

using a captcha is more likely to work to stop spam.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things should be addressed aside from your question first.

1. Inserting unfiltered $_POST values is just asking for a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). At the very least, use [real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
2. Preventing an IP address from registering twice will make your site/service inaccessible to so many potential visitors. Shared IP environments and dynamic IP allocation by ISPs are a just a couple common examples of how many users will be unintentionally blocked.

The answer to your question is to use a select statement and compare the database value to the new IP in question. Give your IP column a unique index. Code is as follows:

```
$conn = new mysqli(/*db info*/);
$res = $conn->query("SELECT $ip FROM members WHERE IP_Address='$ip'");

if (!$res->num_rows) {/*ip wasn't found so insert a new row*/}
else {/*ip was found so return error message*/}
```

Comment: @IsaacBoda No using JS is not secure at all. Any user can alter their own client-side code anytime they like. Only server-side is secure.

Comment: Yea I just noticed that by disabling mine. I'll have to use PHP verification only for this.